# Calculate Subway time

Tags: python

There is a question I'm trying to answer and I have a problem with final outputs.

question:

The names of all stations in this file are in 7 lines. in line, the names of the line stations Metro has come in order and with space. (Note that the name of a station does not contain a space character .)

The train travel time between two stations is 2 minutes
The time required to enter the station where we intend to board the train, 17 minutes
It takes 12 minutes to get out of the station where we are going to walk.
The time we need to change the line is also 10 minutes.
Note that at stations where two lines cross, you can board through both lines and you don't need to wait to change lines.

Mohsen wants not to make his own purchases from Digikala and go shopping by metro. After routing, he understood that he should go from the stations set on the subway and get to the station getting off.

We want you to write a program that calculates the minimum time it takes for Mohsen to reach the shopping place.

file:

```
Tajrish Gheytariyeh Shahid_Sadr Gholhak Doctor_Shari'ati Mirdamad Shahid_Haghani Shahid_Hemmat Mosalla-ye_Emam_Khomeini Shahid_Beheshti Shahid_Mofatteh Shohada-ye_Haftom-e_Tir Taleghani Darvazeh_Dowlat Sa'di Emam_Khomeini Panzdah-e_Khordad Khayyam Meydan-e_Mohammadiyeh Shoush Payaneh_Jonoub Shahid_Bokharaei Ali_Abad Javanmard-e_Ghassab Shahr-e_Rey Palayeshgah Shahed-Bagher_Shahr Haram-e_Motahhar-e_Emam_Khomeini Kahrizak
Farhangsara Tehranpars Shahid_Bagheri Daneshgah-e_Elm-o_San'at Sarsabz Janbazan Fadak Sabalan Shahid_Madani Emam_Hossein Darvazeh_Shemiran Baharestan Mellat Emam_Khomeini Hasan_Abad Daneshgah-e_Emam_Ali Meydan-e_Hor Shahid_Navab-e_Safavi Shademan Daneshgah-e_Sharif Tarasht Tehran_Sadeghiyeh
Gha'em Shahid_Mahallati Aghdasiyeh Nobonyad Hossein_Abad Meydan-e_Heravi Shahid_Zeynoddin Khajeh_Abdollah-e_Ansari Shahid_sayyad-e_Shirazi Shahid_Ghodousi Sohrevardi Shahid_Beheshti Mirza-ye_Shirazi Meydan-e_Jahad Meydan-e_Hazrat-e_Vali_Asr Teatr-e_Shahr Moniriyeh Mahdiyeh Rahahan Javadiyeh Zamzam Shahrak-e_Shari'ati Abdol_Abad Ne'mat_Abad Azadegan
Shahid_Kolahdouz Nirou_Havaei Nabard Pirouzi Ebn-e_Sina Meydan-e_Shohada Darvazeh_Shemiran Darvazeh_Dowlat Ferdowsi Teatr-e_Shahr Meydan-e_Enghelab-e_Eslami Towhid Shademan Doctor_Habibollah Ostad_Mo'in Meydan-e_Azadi Bimeh Shahrk-e_Ekbatan Eram-e_Sabz
Shahid_Sepahbod_Qasem_Soleimani Golshahr Mohammad_Shahr Karaj Atmosfer Garmdarreh Vardavard Iran_Khodro Chitgar Varzeshgah-e_Azadi Eram-e_Sabz Tehran_Sadeghiyeh
Shahid_Sattari Shahid_Ashrafi_Esfahani Yadegar-e_Emam Marzdaran Shahrak-e_Azmayesh Daneshgah-e_Tarbiat_Modarres Meydan-e_Hazrat-e_Vali_Asr Shohada-ye_Haftom-e_Tir Emam_Hossein Meydan-e_Shohada Amir_Kabir Shahid_Rezaei Be'sat Kiyan_Shahr Dowlat_Abad
Meydan-e_San'at Borj-e_Milad-e_Tehran Boostan-e_Goftegou Daneshgah-e_Tarbiat_Modarres Modafean-e_Salamat Towhid Shahid_Navab-e_Safavi Roudaki Komeyl Beryanak Helal_Ahmar Mahdiyeh Meydan-e_Mohammadiyeh Mowlavi Meydan-e_Ghiyam Chehel_Tan-e_Doulab Ahang Basij
```

here is what I've done so far:

```
# tmp = []
results = []

def find_in_list_of_list(mylist, char):
    for sub_list in mylist:
        if char in sub_list:
            return [mylist.index(sub_list), sub_list.index(char)]
    raise ValueError("'{char}' is not in list".format(char=char))


with open("metro.txt", "r") as file:
    lines = [line.split(" ") for line in file.read().split("\n")]

    for i in range(int(input())):
        destination = input().split(" ")

        for line in lines:
            if destination[0] in line and destination[1] in line:
                start = line.index(destination[0])
                stop = line.index(destination[1])
                time = (stop - start) * 2
                results.append(17 + 12 + time)

            elif destination[0] in line and destination[1] not in line:
                start = line.index(destination[0])
                stop = len(line)

                line1 = lines.index(line)
                line2 = find_in_list_of_list(lines, destination[1])

                # tmp.append(line2[1])
                # tmp.append(stop)
                # tmp.append(start)
                time = (stop - line2[1])
                results.append(17 + 12 + time + 10)
            else:
                continue

# print(tmp)
for item in results:
    print(item)
```

my output which is wrong:

```
31
35
43
45
47
46
```

sample input:

```
5
Tajrish Gheytariyeh
Tajrish Gholhak
Tarasht Eram-e_Sabz
Aghdasiyeh Sohrevardi
Towhid Baharestan
```

sample output:

```
31
35
43
45
51
```

description:

The first trip from "Tajrish" to "Qaytaria":

It takes 17 minutes to enter and board the train at Tajrish station.
It takes 2 minutes to reach Qaitariya from "Tajrish" station on line 1.
It takes 12 minutes to get out of "Qaytarieh" station.
Therefore, the total time of this trip is equal to:
17 + 2 + 12 = 31

The second trip from "Tajrish" to "Gholhak":

It takes 17 minutes to enter and board the train at Tajrish station.
It takes 6 minutes to reach "Ghalhak" from "Tajrish" station on line 1.
It takes 12 minutes to leave the "Ghalhak" station.
Therefore, the total time of this trip is equal to:
17 + 6 + 12 = 35

The third journey from "Tarsh" to "Eram Sabz":

It takes 17 minutes to enter and board the train at "Tarsh" station.
It takes 2 minutes to reach "Tehran (Sadeghie)" from "Taresh" station on line 2.
It takes 10 minutes to change direction from line 2 to 5 at "Tehran (Sadegh)" station.
It takes 2 minutes to reach "Eram Sabz" from "Tehran (Sadeghie)" station on line 5.
It takes 12 minutes to leave "Eram Sabz" station.
Therefore, the total time of this trip is equal to:
17 + 2 + 10 + 2 + 12 = 43

The fourth journey from "Aghdiseh" to "Sohrvardi":

It takes 17 minutes to enter and board the train at "Aqdasiyeh" station.
It takes 16 minutes to reach "Sohrvardi" from "Aqdasiyeh" station on line 3.
It takes 12 minutes to get out of "Sohrvardi" station.
Therefore, the total time of this trip is equal to:
17 + 16 + 12 = 45

The fifth journey from "Tawheed" to "Baharistan":

It takes 17 minutes to enter and board the train at "Tawheed" station.
It takes 10 minutes to reach "Darvaze Shemiran" from "Tawheed" station on line 4.
It takes 10 minutes to change direction from line 4 to line 2 at "Darvaze Shemiran" station.
It takes 2 minutes to reach "Baharistan" from "Darvaze Shemiran" station on line 5.
It takes 12 minutes to leave "Baharistan" station.
Therefore, the total time of this trip is equal to:
17 + 10 + 10 + 2 + 12 = 51

Comment: The data you provided does not include any "Ghalhak". How do you know that it takes 6 minutes to reach "Ghalhak" from "Tajrish?

Comment: It exists in the first line of the file.

Comment: The first line has a Gholhak. The closest to a Ghalhak

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find where error exactly is in your code, however I figured rewriting your code could help.

```py
results = []

with open("metro.txt", "r") as file:
    lines = [line.split(" ") for line in file.read().split("\n")]

    for i in range(int(input())):
        destination = input().split(" ")

        for index, line in enumerate(lines):
            if destination[0] in line:
                # start is a tuple - (index of line in lines, index of station in line)
                start = (index, line.index(destination[0]))
            if destination[1] in line:
                stop = (index, line.index(destination[0]))

            # This else is useless, when we are at the end of a for block,
            # we are automatically calling continue
            # else:
            #     continue
        # Calculate travel time and append it to results here, right after the for loop

for item in results:
    print(item)
```

We now know where are the stations exactly in **lines** (you can acess stations like this: `lines[start[0]][start[1]]`). In my opinion now it will be easier to calculate the distances and you don't need `find_in_list_of_list(mylist, char)`.

If you want I can provide you will fully working example, but I think that you want to do it alone.